# Перезапись конкретной строки или переменной в файле LUA

Tags: lua, io

Итак, у меня есть lua скрипт с текстом, например:

```
o.Model = "KK2"
o.Scale = 0.1
o.Pos = Vector:New(0.35, -0.45, -1.3)
o.Ang = Vector:New(0, -1.6, -0.08)
o.WidescreenPos = Vector:New(0.35, -0.45, -1.5)
o.WidescreenAng = Vector:New(0, -1.58, -0.08)

o.ShotCamMove = 0.025
o.ShotCamRotate = 0.025
```

Мне нужно открыть файл при помощи io.open и перезаписать значения переменных o.WidescreenPos и o.WidescreenAng, всё остальное должно остаться неизменным. Как это можно сделать?

Есть несколько разных файлов, где у переменных o.WidescreenPos и o.WidescreenAng разные значения. Поэтому искать по значениям не вариант, нужно заменить эти две строки полностью, на новые, где я уже смогу подставить свои значения. Главный вопрос как найти эти строки и полностью их заменить?

Comment: ¿Почему нельзя просто дописать в конец `o.WidescreenPos = <новое значение>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так, возможны вариации, но принцип вроде должен быть понятен:

```
-- читаем данные из файла 
-- local handle = io.open("data.lua", "wb")
-- local s = handle:read('*all')
--
-- а для примера тут показано просто как в длинной строке s произвести замену
local s= [[
o.Model = "KK2"
o.Scale = 0.1
o.Pos = Vector:New(0.35, -0.45, -1.3)
o.Ang = Vector:New(0, -1.6, -0.08)
o.WidescreenPos = Vector:New(0.35, -0.45, -1.5)
o.WidescreenAng = Vector:New(0, -1.58, -0.08)

o.ShotCamMove = 0.025
o.ShotCamRotate = 0.025
]]


---------- тут производим замену
-- %1 - первое вхождение - искомая переменная
-- %2 - второе вхождение - его заменяем на своё значение
-- %3 - третье вхождение, конец строки 
s = string.gsub(s,"(o.WidescreenPos)(.-)(%c)","%1 = ".. "Vector:New(1, 1, 1)" .."%3")
s = string.gsub(s,"(o.WidescreenAng)(.-)(%c)","%1 = ".. "Vector:New(0, 0, 0)" .."%3")

print(s)

-- ну и пишем строку s в наш файл
-- handle:write(s)
-- handle:close()
```

Comment: я заметил вашу реакцию на ответ, но вы ее удалили, и не понятно, все ли осталось ясно? если что-то нужно уточнить - спросите, возможно что ответ вас устроил, тогда можно отметить ответ как правильный. [Руководствуйтесь этими правилами сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Есть пара ньюансов. Я работаю в старой игрушке, которая написана на lua 5.1 и там много чего нет, в том числе игра не понимает например s:gsub, только string.gsub().
Я плохо разбираюсь в коде, данный пример работает в онлайн компиляторе, но мне он не подошел. Возможно тут можно что-то подправить?

Comment: да, я поправил ответ. Можно использовать `string.gsub()`.Через двоеточие - это просто сокращенная запись обращения к функции.

Comment: и да, пример для компилятора и написан. А в ресальности нужно раскомментировать строки с открытием, чтением данных,  записью  и закрытием файла. А  объявление `local s= [[ ]]` - убрать.